# Python Flask TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask, streaming, telegram

i am trying to make a file streamer from telegram in flask

code i used

```
from flask import Response

@app.route("/dl/<hash>", methods=["GET"])
async def download(hash):
  body = yield_file()
  return Response(
        status=206 if range_header else 200,
        response=body,
        headers={
            "Content-Type": f"{mime_type}",
            "Content-Range": f"bytes {from_bytes}-{until_bytes}/{file_size}",
            "Content-Length": str(req_length),
            "Content-Disposition": f'{disposition}; filename="{file_name}"',
            "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        },
    )
```

where the yield_file() function i took from https://github.com/EverythingSuckz/TG-FileStreamBot/blob/3f7304fa023e373e873c05abe431aafd537020fe/WebStreamer/utils/custom_dl.py#L164

in the repo he used aiohttp web server and it works fine there

but in flask it gives the following error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2023 22:21:06] "GET /dl/jRtYoKqEu6 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 364, in run_wsgi       
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 327, in execute        
    for data in application_iter:
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 289, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\response.py", line 32, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

can i know whats the problem here and how to fix that

**Edit :**

Maybe the problem is because of this https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/41b74e7a92685bc18b6a472bd10524bba20cb4a2/src/werkzeug/wrappers/response.py#L32

It is using `for` keyword instead of `async for`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
import asyncstdlib

async for i, numbers in asyncstdlib.enumerate(gen_random_numbers()):
print(f"working with the batch {i}  and processing {numbers}")

Comment: I dint understand, where i should use it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).